# Фильтрация DataGrid связанной с объектом DataTable (WPF)

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid, datatable

Как  в WPF сделать фильтрацию `DataGrid`, связанную с объектом `DataTable`?

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы отфильтровать datagrid, вам нужно создать string и построить его

```
Grid myParent; 
string strFilterResult;
string strFilter; 
string str;

string dType=myParent.dataSetOffice.Tables[myParent.strTable].
Columns[i].DataType.FullName.ToString().Remove(0,7);
```

А дальше нужно проверять, например:

```
if (textBox1.Text != "" && dType=="Int32") 
{
    str += " and " + "id" + "=" + textBox1.Text;
} 
if (textBox2.Text != "" && dType == "String") 
{ 
    str += " and " + "string" +" like'%"+textBox2.Text+"%'";
}

strFilter = str.Substring(0, 4);
strFilterResult = strFilter;
if (strFilterResult == " and")
{
    strFilterResult = str.Remove(0, 4);
}
```

И это всё я повесил на button.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответ! В ожидании его, я сделал сам через

```
{
    BindingListCollectionView tarelkiViewSource =  (BindingListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(tarelkiTableAdapter.GetData()); // создание представления данных ADO.NET

    if(tarelkiViewSource!=null)
    {
        tarelkiViewSource.CustomFilter="tmin=4";//фильтрация данных
    }
    grid.DataContext = tarelkiViewSource;//привязка данных к сетке окна
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще в XML по определёному полю к примеру

```
 <dxg:GridColumn Header="Time Data"  FieldName="TimeData" SortMode="DisplayText" SortOrder="Ascending"/>
```